# jQuery.ajax: "An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable"

Tags: jquery, ajax, binary

I'm trying to read some binary data from the server, and it works fine this way:

```
var xml = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");

xml.open("GET", "/some.php", true);
xml.responseType = "arraybuffer";

xml.onreadystatechange = myHandler; // myHandler here seems to be irrelevant

xml.send();
```

However if I try to do the same thing with jquery like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/some.php",
    xhrFields: {
        responseType: "arraybuffer"
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.readyState);
        console.log(xhr.statusText); // is: [Exception... "An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable"  code: "11" nsresult: "0x8053000b (InvalidStateError)" ...
    }
});
```

I can't get the results in `myHandler`, since it's returning with an error "An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable" on this [line in jquery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/xhr.js#L85) - apparently `xhr` is no longer usable at that point. What's the best way to handle this?

It's actually the same on stackoverflow: go to /, type this in firebug console:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/",
        xhrFields: {
            responseType: "arraybuffer"
        },
        complete: function(xhr) {
            console.log(xhr.readyState);
            console.log(xhr.statusText);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide some more details? What are you attempting to access in the `myHandler` function?

Comment: @Brad M, updated the question. You can see the error yourself on stackoverflow, and, presumably, other domains

Comment: Have you tried using the second argument passed to the complete callback, "textStatus"? Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish?